# Does anyone know how to identity colour names from Dulux?

Tags: paint

Does anyone know how to accurately identify colour names from Dulux using a website from a pixel of colour on a computer screen? Thanks

For example, this colour:

[image]

Comment: Picking colour from a computer screen is probably the worst way.  You want a paint sample held in your hand.  You can adjust a screen to give 15 different shades of that/any colour.

Comment: I am trying to identify these for puzzle…

Comment: You will need to know what names dulux uses for their colours and then try to match.  Google reverse image search might help.  I might guess something wine for the name, but I probably be completely wrong.  It looks like some shade in the red/pink/purple range.

Comment: @PDT, this question appears to be off-topic for this site, because your comment says it's about solving puzzles, not home improvement. If you edit the question to orient it toward home improvement, it may stand a better chance being on topc.

Comment: tbh, whether it's for a game or a real need to identify a colour, the answer is the same - it's unlikely to be accurate, but there is a practical method to achieve it.

Comment: Color expert here.  You cannot make the leap from an RGB screen color to a print or paint color.  This concept just does not work.  The colors are created completely different ways: screen is additive red + green + blue in adjusted proportions.  Print is cyan, magenta, yellow and black.  Paint is a dozen pigments that vary by system.  Many colors possible in one system are out of gamut for another. Heck I have an orange made with old toxic mineral pigments that is out of gamut for safe modern pigments!  The best you can do is eyeball it off a screen. Get a Munsell Book of Color and good luck!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I agree… but the manufacturer provides swatches online [whether that's wise or not] so the issue is to match to one of those [whether it's accurate or not…]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether this is for a puzzle or the wife just emailed you a swatch of her favourite colour & you have to buy the right paint… today - the issue is the same.

If you don't know the provenance of your swatch you've not much hope.
Your sample here has a profile of Display P3… whether that's the original profile or someone made a screenshot on a recent Mac… we don't know.
[The exif data, which is mainly stripped on upload to imgur for privacy reasons, makes it a little hard to tell if it's from a Mac or an iPhone - it's definitely an Apple device.]

How accurate their screen & profile was… we don't know.

How that profile translates to sRGB, which is likely the profile used by Dulux… we don't know.

If your screen, or that of the person supplying the swatch isn't true - almost no screen not professionally calibrated is true, and most people's computers make an awful job of translating colour - we don't know.

That means you cannot absolutely know when you found a match.

Ignoring all the above & hoping you get lucky, practically you do it by floating your swatch out over the Dulux page, then initially guided by eye, you hover an accurate colour meter over each swatch until you find one with the closest numbers.

On a fully-calibrated system, I can get this close. It's not perfect, but we don't know how accurate the swatch was.

[image]

Of course, with all these inaccuracies, and an additional translation to illumination that will not be in most cases full cloudy-sky daylight, you've little hope of the colour on your wall being what you hoped it would be from the computer image.
This is the equivalent of [Chinese Whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) for colour.